# Is using molar terms with maxwells relations misguided?

Tags: thermodynamics

My professor wants me to do a lot of derivations using maxwells relations. One of the things he wants me to prove is that from the Van der Waals equation of state one can say:

$\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial \bar{V}}\Big)_T=\frac{a}{\bar{V}^2}$

But I completely object to using molar variables here. For example in class I once had to prove the change in entropy of an isothermal process for a system that follows this equation of state:

$P=\frac{RT}{\bar{V}-b}-\frac{a}{T\bar{V}^2}$ and I got an equation of the type:

$\Delta S = nR Ln(\frac{Vf-nb}{Vi-nb})+\frac{an^2}{T^2}\big(\frac{Vf-Vi}{VfVi}\big)$

Where clearly the dependence of entropy on the quantity of moles in the system was not simply linear. If you worked with molar quantities you would've got:

$\Delta S* = R Ln(\frac{\bar{Vf}-b}{\bar{Vi}-b})+\frac{a}{T^2}\big(\frac{\bar{Vf}-\bar{Vi}}{\bar{Vf}\bar{Vi}}\big)$

Where I put an asterisk to remind you that this isn't entropy, I think it's a completely misguided calculation.

I understand the temptation to want to get a "molar quantity" by using "molar terms" but this is simply not going to happen. It doesn't make any sense to use molar quantities when using Maxwells relations except if you are calculating what would happen to the system if there was only one mole of quantity which is still sort of invalid since there will not be any dimensional homogeneity.

Is this right?

Thanks.

Comment: Number of moles is related to number of particles via Avogadro's constant. I'm sorry, but I'm not seeing what the big deal is here. Just replace $n$ with $N/N_A$.

Comment: I think my point is clear on the entropy equation I got. If you worked with the molar quantities then $n$ wouldn't be there at all. Which gives you the temptation of "Oh, this means I can multiply that equation by $n$ for any system and get the real entropy". Well thats wrong, because of the weird dependence there exists with moles here.

Comment: I added what the equation would look like if we would've used the molar variables.